# Passing data to server Xamarin JSON

Tags: json, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am sending data to my server. The total number of date is more than 2000. I am sending the data one at a time. How can I send the data all at once? It takes so long for the data to be sent. I am using JSON Objects to send my data. How can I get the all the data from my local database and send it to my server all at once?

```
var sql = "SELECT * FROM tblContacts WHERE Coordinator = '" + contact + "'";
var getContacts = conn.QueryAsync<ContactsTable>(sql);
var resultCount = getContacts.Result.Count;
var current_datetime = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:00");

if(resultCount > 0)
{
   for (int i = 0; i < resultCount; i++)
   {
       var result = getContacts.Result[i];
       var contactID = result.ContactID;
       var fileAs = result.FileAs;
       var firstName = result.FirstName;
       var middleName = result.MiddleName;
       var lastName = result.LastName;

       var link = Constants.requestUrl + "Host=" + host + "&Database=" + database + "&Contact=" + contact + "&Request=nLm8YE";
       string contentType = "application/json";
       Object json = new JObject
       {
          { "ContactID", contactID },
          { "FileAs", fileAs },
          { "FirstName", firstName },
          { "MiddleName", middleName },
          { "LastName", lastName }
        };

        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        var response = await client.PostAsync(link, new StringContent(json.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, contentType));
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put it into a JArray:

```
if(resultCount > 0)
{
   JArray arr = new JArray();
   for (int i = 0; i < resultCount; i++)
   {
       var result = getContacts.Result[i];
       var contactID = result.ContactID;
       var fileAs = result.FileAs;
       var firstName = result.FirstName;
       var middleName = result.MiddleName;
       var lastName = result.LastName;

       var link = Constants.requestUrl + "Host=" + host + "&Database=" + database + "&Contact=" + contact + "&Request=nLm8YE";
       string contentType = "application/json";
       Object json = new JObject
       {
          { "ContactID", contactID },
          { "FileAs", fileAs },
          { "FirstName", firstName },
          { "MiddleName", middleName },
          { "LastName", lastName }
        };
        arr.Add(json);          
   }
   HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        var response = await client.PostAsync(link, new StringContent(arr.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, contentType));
}
```

however this would require your enpoint to accept the incoming data as an array and being able to iterate and consume it on the server side.

Comment: Will it work with my php here is my code? **$json_str = file_get_contents('php://input');
        $json_obj = json_decode($json_str);
        
        $ContactID = $json_obj->ContactID;**

Comment: you will probably need tp adapt your code to accept an array and for each entry in the array to create a new object, parse the data and store it.